# p:selectCheckboxMenu Need Label for selecting all

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Am tring to add label for check box [That is for checking all Checkboxs] `p:selectCheckboxMenu` as in the figure.

[image]

Here is the Code:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{dashBoardController.selectedColumns}" 
                          styleClass="ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header" 
                          label="Custom" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                          panelStyle="width:220px">

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Status" itemValue="status"/>                    
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="group name" itemValue="groupName"/>                    
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header:before
{
    content: "All";
}
```

any suggestions ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some 5 min of `CSS` fights, i discover some maneer to do it (i think its not the normal way to do, but i did not find other way).

You can use the `content` style property to atach content to an html element from `css`. The `p:selectCheckboxMenu` header class is `.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header`, so, if you try this:

```
// on your css file
.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header:before
{
    content: "MY TEXT FOR SELECTING ALL ON MANY CHECKBOX MENU";
}
```

you will have the expected result. More info about content property, visit [this](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/) link.

Note: I recommed to give an `css id` on the specific `p:selectCheckboxMenu` to have the pretended title. If you wonna for all `p:selectCheckboxMenu` you can use the code as it's.

Hope it helps ^^

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps but, small issue. I have updated the question please take a look. @ColdHack

Comment: Did you give an `css class` to the specific `p:selectCheckboxMenu`? And you dont need to add `styleClass="ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header"`, this is the default `css` class (use inspect element from the browser to see it). Instead of `styleClass="ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header"` try `styleClass="check-box-test-style"`, and replace `.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header:before` for `.check-box-test-style.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header:before`.

Comment: Hai @ColdHack Small issue now. Its overriding the CSS class and showing all the places the same text. How do i change only for one selectcheckboxmenu??

Comment: Its not working when i keep like this '.check-box-test-style.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header:before'  Working when overriding with out 'check-box-test-style'

Comment: Hi @SuryaDev. If you wonna show the text for one `p:selectCheckboxMenu`, you need set a unique css style class for the component (like `<p:selectCheckboxMenu styleClass="check-box-test-style"`).